# Friendly Blog Url Isapi Rewrite Regex

Tags: regex, seo, isapi

My regex isn't great, and I'm struggling here. I need regex to get title from these 2 formats:

```
http://domain.com/blog/title
http://secure.com/domainkey/blog/title
```

but not match anything from (where subfolders could be multiple):

```
http://domain.com/images/blog/imagename
http://domain.com/images/subfolders/blog/imagename
http://secure.com/domain/images/blog/imagename
http://secure.com/domain/images/subfolders/blog/imagename
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Probably getting the whole isapi rewrite 2 rule set for this would be better than strictly some regex.

Comment: I had started with

`RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*) /content\?friendly_name=$1 [I,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/blog/(.*) /content\?friendly_name=$2 [I,L]`

but, of course, I'm getting http://domain.com/images/sub/blog/this.png returning a match.

Comment: Basically, I guess ignore "/blog" if it's after "/images" or "/files".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(http:\/\/(?:(?:secure.com\/domainkey)|(?:domain.com))\/blog\/)([\w-]+)
```

capture two parts:

1. base url, `http://domain.com/blog/` or `http://secure.com/domainkey/blog/`
2. the title

demo with js:

```
var regex = /(http:\/\/(?:(?:secure.com\/domainkey)|(?:domain.com))\/blog\/)([\w-]+)/ig;

regex.exec('http://domain.com/blog/blog-title');
// results: ["http://domain.com/blog/blog-title", "http://domain.com/blog/", "blog-title"]

regex.exec('http://secure.com/domainkey/blog/blog-title')
// results: ["http://secure.com/domainkey/blog/blog-title", "http://secure.com/domainkey/blog/", "blog-title"]
```

assumed that blog title only contains [a-zA-Z_-], if you have more characters to capture, please modify the last part of the regex.